# Set range variable = printarea

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to set a range variable = to current print area.

```
dim rng as range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea
```

There is more to it than this, but this is where I am getting stuck, Getting a
Run-time error '424':
Object required

I am assuming this is because the printarea is text and the variable I am using is set as a range.  How do I get my rng variable set to printarea range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the PrintArea is already assigned a value you can turn it into a range object like this:

```
Dim rng As Range

'This has to be set or print area returns a blank string
'which will cause the set statement below to throw an error
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:B1"

Set rng = Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it was something fairly easy, just couldn't find an example of it.  This worked great.

Comment: remember that PrintArea might return "" (blank string) if there is no print area, in which case this code will barf, so you may want to check for that if there's any chance the PrintArea isn't set